# Can gluing of morphisms of locally ringed spaces be expressed by an exact sequence?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ and $(Y,\mathcal{O}_Y)$ are locally ringed spaces. Then *morphisms glue*, that is, if $\{U_i\}_i$ is an open cover of $X$, then "to give a morphism $X\to Y$ is the same as giving morphisms $U_i\to Y$ that agree on overlaps".

This sentence is formally similar to the sentence that expresses the condition a presheaf needs to satisfy in order to be a sheaf. So one can try to say that the above sentence can be expressed as: there is an exact sequence

$0\to Mor(X,Y)\to \prod_i Mor(U_i, Y)\to \prod_{i,j} Mor(U_i\cap U_j,Y)$

and I have just seen this in a couple of solutions I found online to an exercise in Hungerford.

However I can't make sense of this. The first map would be $f\mapsto (f|_{U_i})$, but what would be the second map? The expression $(f_i)\mapsto ((f_i-f_j)|_{U_i\cap U_j})$ doesn't make sense, does it? What does it mean to substract morphisms of ringed spaces? And more importantly, what does exactness of the final arrow mean?

Am I missing something obvious? Is there any way around this?

Comment: Perhaps I should just ditch solution guides to Hartshorne, as suggested in a comment to [my previous post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/549253/hartshorne-exercise-ii-2-18-a-ring-morphism-is-surjective-if-it-induces-a-home)...

Comment: This is really a statement saying the image of the first is the equalizer of the second *set* of arrows (which ones?), and the first map is an injection. It's technically incorrect, but intuitively useful notation.

Comment: The point being, of course, that one can just as easily define sheaves of sets, and the presheaf $U \mapsto \mathrm{Mor}(U, Y)$ is a sheaf.